# Code to be executed only when application is run outside of visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, configuration

I have a WPF windows application that makes a call to a DLL for registration.
I need this code to be called only when the application is run outside of visual studio.
In other words, when clicking run from within the visual studio, I dont want this code executed but want it executed if EXE is called outside of visual studio.

Is there a way where I can do that withouht having to keep commenting and uncommenting this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the preprocessor:

```
#if DEBUG
   code to run during debug mode only
#else
   normal code
#endif
```

or the Conditional attribute

```
[Conditional("DEBUG")]
private void SomeMethod()
{
 stuff
}
```

Comment: Sidenote:  I would recommend the conditional attribute, as using the preprocesser doesn't play well with intellisense.

Comment: This is a solution - but you should mention that you should compile with DEBUG mode - both solutions do not check if you are within Visual Studio! Only if the code is compiled with DEBUG mode.